# When is it safe to plant vegtables outside in Denver, Colorado?

Tags: vegetables, urban-gardening, planting-times, snow

When is the last frost in Denver, Colorado?

Officially, March 20th is the last day of winter, but when is it safe to plant seeds or seedling in Denver, Colorado (in terms of snow or freeing tempuratures?)

Comment: It depends on the vegetable.

Comment: Go to https://www.almanac.com/gardening/planting-calendar and put in your zip code, it'll help with planting times but the best thing to do is identify your hardiness zone - I found mine originally through the local garden center when I happened to be there.

Comment: You might want to visit these folks for some locally applicable tips as well: https://extension.colostate.edu/topic-areas/yard-garden/growing-food-and-growing-gardeners/

Answer (score 1):

The "last day of winter" or spring equinox has nothing to do with last frost date. Or last snow date.

**Average** last frost date for any particular location can be found from various sources, most of which (in the USA) are derived from National Weather Service published data, including 30-year climate normals.

Actual last frost date will vary, and may be earlier or later than the average. Not planting all your seeds or started plants at once is a typical coping strategy to cover the possibility that last frost (actual) may be earlier or later than the average. Being prepared to cover plants in the event of frost is also a coping strategy.

Comment: There is an option to answer one's own question Q and A style. There is even a little check box for it. That way, somone typing a question into a search engine can find the question, and there will ready be an answer waiting for them. They won't have to wait for an answer. I posted an answer to this question less than 5 minutes after I asked it, but a moderator or bot deleted it.

Comment: You posted a spammy answer promoting a certain site. It was evidently deleted as such.